# postgresql log about no existing database

Tags: postgresql, logging

I don't understand this postgresql log :

```
2022-03-27 08:00:19.441 UTC [584262] postgres@boutique2 FATAL:  database "boutique2" does not exist
2022-03-27 08:00:19.704 UTC [584264] postgres@boutique2 FATAL:  database "boutique2" does not exist
2022-03-27 08:01:54.770 UTC [781] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-03-27 08:01:54.773 UTC [781] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-03-27 08:01:54.779 UTC [781] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 800) exited with exit code 1
2022-03-27 08:01:54.780 UTC [795] LOG:  shutting down
2022-03-27 08:01:54.797 UTC [781] LOG:  database system is shut down
2022-03-27 08:02:16.254 UTC [770] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.5 (Debian 13.5-0+deb11u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-03-27 08:02:16.255 UTC [770] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-03-27 08:02:16.256 UTC [770] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-03-27 08:02:16.271 UTC [772] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-03-27 08:01:54 UTC
2022-03-27 08:02:16.285 UTC [770] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-03-27 08:02:17.243 UTC [891] postgres@boutique2 FATAL:  database "boutique2" does not exist
2022-03-27 08:02:17.640 UTC [1044] postgres@boutique2 FATAL:  database "boutique2" does not exist
```

I dropped this database, which is not present in my mojolicious scripts, the only ones on this server.

```
root@perso:/etc/postgresql/13/main# grep postgresql.conf -e 'boutique2'
root@perso:/etc/postgresql/13/main# grep pg_hba.conf -e 'boutique2'
root@perso:/etc/postgresql/13/main#
```

Has please someone an idea about ?

Comment: Something is still looking for the database. To your question add the line before the FATAL one.

Comment: @Adrian : I did it.

Comment: You have a tool or program that tries to connect to that non-existing database. It's nothing you can find in your config files.

Comment: Perhaps munin-node ? I did a dpkg-reconfigure, I will see the result.